# Продвижение контента на другие страны

Tags: seo

Вижу, что периодично пользователи заходят с других стран. Собственно, соответствующие языки добавил.

Для того, чтобы продвинуть статью как на русскоязычный сегмент, так и на англоязычный. Достаточно просто выполнить перевод статьи?

То есть публикация в поисковой выдаче, а именно снипет. Будет так же ползти к топу если будет соответствующий перевод? При этом url будет один и тот же...

Если бы американец вбил ключевую фразу и русский, снипет будет ориентировочно у одного и другого на тех же позициях?

Тут самое главное поведенческий фактор или я что путаю?

Comment: "При этом url будет один и тот же..." - вероятно вы можете объяснить: как два различных языка могут быть на одной странице?

Comment: Знаем язык пользователя, отображаем соответствующий перевод. В бд, создаем дубликат статьи с тем же url

Comment: Гугл говорит: Если вы динамически изменяете контент или осуществляете переадресацию с учетом языковых настроек, учитывайте, что Google может обнаружить не все версии ваших страниц. Это происходит потому, что обычно робот Googlebot запускается из США и отправляет запросы HTTP без параметра Accept-Language в заголовке. - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites#use-different-urls-for-different-language-versions